# Error when reading block of a file in php

Tags: php

My code is :

```
$fileName = 'http://www.test.com/test.txt';
$fileRes = fopen($fileName,'rb');
fseek($fileRes, -100,  SEEK_END);
$content = fread($fileRes, 10);
```

It gives this error :

```
Warning: fseek() [function.fseek]: stream does not support seeking in /home/skrsoft/public_html/a.php on line 10
```

This error is returned for all files ! Why ?

Comment: Because the *["stream does not support seeking"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php)*.

Answer (score 2):

You are opening HTTP stream and not a local file.

You cannot use fseek, but you can check the content-length header, if it is sent, and skip (with `fread()` but without assigning to `$content`) as many bytes as needed

Answer (score 1):

You can't use fseek with fopen file pointers that use ftp:// or http:// move the file local before using fseek.